# Show div from parent on hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover

Im still learning jQuery and I'm having a little trouble working out what i need to do... I need to have markers on a map and when you roll over them they show information. So I have two problems I'm not sure of:

1) How do you make the div hide again when the hover is released?
2) How do I write the code so that the div of parent is the only one that opens rather than all of them?

```js
$(function() {
$(".block").hover(function(){
 $('.popup').show();
 });
});
```

```css
 .wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #efefef;
  margin: 0 auto;
 } 

 .block {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #8E2729;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .block:hover{
   background-color: #5151B7;
 }
 
 .block-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 130px;
 }
 
 .block-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 500px;
 }
 
 .block-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 100px;
 }
 
 .popup {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #4E4E4E;
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -80px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="block block-1">
  <div class="popup">This is some popup text for block 1</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="block block-2">
  <div class="popup">This is some popup text for block 2</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="block block-3">
  <div class="popup">This is some popup text for block 3</div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I just worked out the hide on release - changing 'show' to 'toggle'. Im assuming thats right? So its just making it only open the child div that I need help with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `childern()` method.The `children()` method returns all direct children of the selected element.Define two function for `hover()` method.The `hover()` method specifies two functions to run when the mouse pointer hovers over the selected elements.This method triggers both the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

```
$(function() {
$(".block").hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.popup').show();
    },function(){
  $(this).children('.popup').hide();
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
$(".block").hover(function(){
 $(this).children('.popup').show();
 },function(){
  $(this).children('.popup').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #efefef;
  margin: 0 auto;
 } 

 .block {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #8E2729;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .block:hover{
   background-color: #5151B7;
 }
 
 .block-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 130px;
 }
 
 .block-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 500px;
 }
 
 .block-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 100px;
 }
 
 .popup {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #4E4E4E;
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -80px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="block block-1">
  <div class="popup">This is some popup text for block 1</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="block block-2">
  <div class="popup">This is some popup text for block 2</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="block block-3">
  <div class="popup">This is some popup text for block 3</div>
 </div>

</div>
```

See fiddle here [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hek_Mat/h9daLow1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggle` rather then `show` and `find` popup inside associate div .

```js
$(function() {
$(".block").hover(function(){
 $(this).find('.popup').toggle();
 });
});
```

```css
 .wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #efefef;
  margin: 0 auto;
 } 

 .block {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #8E2729;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .block:hover{
   background-color: #5151B7;
 }
 
 .block-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 130px;
 }
 
 .block-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 500px;
 }
 
 .block-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 100px;
 }
 
 .popup {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #4E4E4E;
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -80px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="block block-1">
  <div class="popup">This is some popup text for block 1</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="block block-2">
  <div class="popup">This is some popup text for block 2</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="block block-3">
  <div class="popup">This is some popup text for block 3</div>
 </div>

</div>
```